# How to remove "" and white spaces from this string

Tags: php

I have returned a string variable goes like this:

```
"""

                    65,000
                
"""
```

As you can see there are some `"""` and some `white spaces` at the beginning and at the end of value.

So now I wonder how can I remove all these `"` double quotations and white spaces, so only `65,000` would remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `trim()` function:

```
$response = '"""

                    65,000
                
"""';
$clean_response = trim($response, '" \n\t\r');
```

You can also use `preg_replace()`

```
$clean_response = preg_replace('^"+\s*|\s*"+$', '', $response);
```

This is also a bit more specific in that it only replaces quotes at the beginning and end, it won't replace quotes that are after the initial whitespace.

Comment: `\n` is just `\n`, not linebreak

Comment: not working somehow

Comment: Instead of `'" \n'` try `" \"\t\n\r"`.